# Why does google cloud vision Logo detection return different results on the same image?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I have been playing around with the google cloud vision API, namely the logo detection feature. Basically I want to determine if an image is a logo, so I run it through the API. However, I always get different results every time I run it. Sometimes the API classifies it as a logo, and sometimes it does not. Is there any explanation for this and possibly a way to improve the accuracy?

EDIT: I have just determined what the problem really is. I am trying to detect logos on remote images on a public facing website, and occasionally (but not all the time) the following error is returned:

```
I20180409-21:25:38.090(8)?     error: 
I20180409-21:25:38.091(8)?      { details: [],
I20180409-21:25:38.091(8)?        code: 13,
I20180409-21:25:38.091(8)?        message: 'We can not access the URL 
currently. Please download the content and pass it in.' },
```

What is the cause for this issue and is there a way around it?

Comment: Google Cloud Support would be the right place for this discussion.

Comment: They did mention on their page that google engineers would monitor the google-cloud-vision tag on stackoverflow

Comment: You should share the image you are using for this discussion, and probably you don't want to publish it. If publishing the image is ok for you, make it available somehow please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by downloading the image as a base64 encoded image and then passing that into the google vision API instead of the url

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it with [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/LOGO%20/vision/v1/vision.images.annotate?_h=2&resource=%257B%250A++%2522requests%2522%253A+%250A++%255B%250A++++%257B%250A++++++%2522image%2522%253A+%250A++++++%257B%250A++++++++%2522source%2522%253A+%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522imageUri%2522%253A+%2522http%253A%252F%252Fwww.brandemia.org%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2011%252F10%252Flogo_2003.jpg%2522%250A++++++++%257D%250A++++++%257D%252C%250A++++++%2522features%2522%253A+%250A++++++%255B%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522type%2522%253A+%2522LABEL_DETECTION%2522%250A++++++++%257D%250A++++++%255D%250A++++%257D%250A++%255D%250A%257D&), with the same logo (in my example, same imageUri) I always got the same result. For [this image](http://www.brandemia.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/logo_2003.jpg), I am always getting below result for logo:

```
 "mid": "/m/0dwx7",
 "description": "logo",
 "score": 0.63438356,
 "topicality": 0.63438356
```

You can try it with [this link](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/LOGO%20/vision/v1/vision.images.annotate?_h=2&resource=%257B%250A++%2522requests%2522%253A+%250A++%255B%250A++++%257B%250A++++++%2522image%2522%253A+%250A++++++%257B%250A++++++++%2522source%2522%253A+%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522imageUri%2522%253A+%2522http%253A%252F%252Fwww.brandemia.org%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2011%252F10%252Flogo_2003.jpg%2522%250A++++++++%257D%250A++++++%257D%252C%250A++++++%2522features%2522%253A+%250A++++++%255B%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522type%2522%253A+%2522LABEL_DETECTION%2522%250A++++++++%257D%250A++++++%255D%250A++++%257D%250A++%255D%250A%257D&) and let me know if the output is different.

Comment: I just determined the problem, the API sometimes returns an error on the image and says 'We can not access the URL currently. Please download the content and pass it in.' . Is there a particular reason for this and how can I fix it? Aside from downloading the image in base64 and passing that in?

Comment: I am not aware of the error you mentioned, would it be possible to share the URL so I can try to reproduce the issue?